# SecurityNegotiationException raises for WCF Service client

Tags: c#, wcf, service, https

I have a WCF Service secured in with Username and Password.
I wrote a simple client but when I try to call Web Service method I receive SecurityNegotiationException exception.

The configuration of Web service looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServ.Service1"
           behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConfiguration"
              contract="MyServ.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyServ.CustomValidator, MyServ"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client procedure looks like this:

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(@"https://localhost:8083/MyServ/Service1.svc");

        using (var service = new Service1Client(binding, endpointAddress))
        {
            var loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
            loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"user";
            loginCredentials.UserName.Password = @"password";

            var defaultCredentials = service.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
            service.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials); //remove default ones
            service.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials); //add required ones

            var data = service.GetData(100);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Everytime I service.GetData(100) is executed I receive SecurityNegotiationException exception.

Anyone can help?

Comment: As an idea... can you initialise  service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and  and ervice.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password instead creating a new one and deleting deleting default ClientCredentials

Comment: I have followed your advice, but it didn't help. The same error exists.

Comment: COuld you check in debugger if you you getting in Validate method on your server Validator?

Comment: That is another problem. I am not getting Validate method. Could you guess why?

Answer (score 0):

there might a lot of reasons for that. unfortuntely WCF error messages does not give you a clear hint about what went wrong.

If I were you I would suggest the following road map:

1. Checked firewall rule. See if your 8083 port is open
2. Check if SLL certificate is properly subscribed `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8083 certhash={your hash} appid={your id}`
3. Temporary set `your security mode` to `None` and test to see the wcf service website (wsdl site)
4. if you can see the wcf service site than adjust your client to `None security mode` and try to call a method. If does not work. Try to run your client `as Admin` under very powerfull user
5. When there is no issue with WCF service under HTTPS than spet in into Auth by user name and password